# 3 row CSS div design

Tags: css, html

I am trying to make 3 div's in row design. Where the header and footer have fixed height. 
The center div expands to fill the empty space. I have tried but the closest I got is the code below. Still having problems with the center div which expands over the footer div.

html:

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id='rowOne'>row 1</div>
    <div id='rowTwo'>row 2</div>
    <div id='rowThree'>row 3</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#rowOne {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: green;
}
#rowTwo {
    width: 100%;
    background: limegreen;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#rowThree {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    clear: both;
    background: green;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    height:50px;
}
#container {
    height: 100%;
}
```

[image]

Comment: what exactly do you need can you please post the image of your desired result..........

Comment: That's sticky footer! Check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three Row pure CSS

I know this post is getting on a bit, but despite claims to the contrary, you can do this very simply with CSS. No need for JavaScript, jQuery, CSS 3 hacks etc.

Here's a couple of jsf's that show fixed header and footer and dynamic body div.

This first one shows fixed pixel height header and footer and dynamic body **EXACTLY** as you wanted in your image

http://jsfiddle.net/LBQ7K/

```
<body>
<div class="header"><p>Header</p></div>
<div class="cssBody"><p>Hello World</p></div>
<div class="footer"><p>Footer</p></div>
</body>

html, body, {
height: 100%;
}

.header {
position:   absolute;
top:    0px;
height:     50px;
width:      100%;
background: #f00;
}

.footer {
position:   absolute;
bottom: 0;
height:     50px;
width:      100%;
background: #00f;
}

.cssBody {
position:   absolute;
top:    50px;
bottom: 50px;
width:  100%;
background: #0f0;
}
```

The second shows you can use the same technique to have dynamic headers & footers.
http://jsfiddle.net/reqXJ/

```
    <body>
    <div class="header"><p>Header</p></div>
    <div class="cssBody"><p>Hello World</p></div>
    <div class="footer"><p>Footer</p></div>
</body>

html, body, {
    height: 100%;
}

.header {
    position:   absolute;
    top:        0px;
    height:     15%;
    width:      100%;
    background: #f00;
}

.footer {
    position:   absolute;
    bottom:     0;
    height:     15%;
    width:      100%;
    background: #00f;
}

.cssBody {
    position:   absolute;
    top:        15%;
    bottom:     15%;
    width:      100%;
    background: #0f0;
}
```

Comment: There is a problem with scrollbars when body text is longer see http://jsfiddle.net/xHnTM/

Comment: jsfiddle.net/xHnTM/12 seems to be better. There is no body body scrollbar but to be honest after three years I am not perfectly sure what I was complaining for.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common problem, one of the solutions that worked for me is from the following website:

http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

with the code:

http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/layout.css

and another popular choice:

http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

If this does not meet your needs, let us know, we can help more.

Comment: all this sollutions expand the center div behind the footer div. I want a solution with each div having only his own space.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are try to do a sticky footer, well... you will need a few hacks:

### HTML:

```
<div id='container'>
   <div class="header">
      <h1>Sticky Footer!</h1>
   </div>
   <div id='rowOne'>row 1</div>
   <div id='rowTwo'>row 2</div>
   <div id='rowThree'>row 3</div>
   <div class="push"></div>
</div>
<div id='footer'></div>
```

### CSS

```
.container {
   min-height: 100%;
   height: auto !important;height: 100%; 
   /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
   margin: 0 auto -142px;
}
.footer, .push{
   height: 142px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}
```

**Note:** Replace the footer and push height for your fixed height and don't forget to insert the push div after the rows in the container.

Answer (score 0):

You can fake this by absolutely positioning the rows, and adding padding to top and bottom for the middle row. You cannot do this like you were doing with tables

```
#container { position:relative; height:800px } // needs height

#rowOne, #rowTwo, #rowThree { position:absolute }

#rowOne { top:0; left:0 }
#rowThree { bottom:0; left:0 }

#rowTwo { left:0; top:0; padding:50px 0; } // top and bottom padding 50px
```

Answer (score 0):

could this line of code help?
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yaSWM/72/)

Try this:

```
#container{
   ...
   position:relative;
}
#content{
   min-height: xxx;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should exactly do what you want:

#### html code:

```
<div id="header">
    header
</div>
<div id='container'>
    <div id='rowOne'>one</div>
    <div id='rowTwo'>two</div>
    <div id='rowThree'>three</div>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div id="footer">
    footer
</div>
```

#### CSS code:

```
.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}
#header, #footer {
    background-color: red;
}
#container {
    width: 100%;
}
#rowOne {
    width: 25%;
    background: green;
    float: left;
} 
#rowTwo {
    width: 55%;
    height: 100px;
    background: limegreen;
    float: left;
}
#rowThree {
    width: 20%;
    background: green;
    float: left;
}​
```

You can also test it on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vz9RL/1/)

Comment: I'm having problems ... it always says that I have to format the link -> I've just used html code: Please make your answer complete by including relevant, formatted code inline (don't just link to jsfiddle.net).

Comment: You know SO use [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/basics) syntax right?

Comment: It has always worked so far, however thx for the info and for editing ;)

Comment: You're welcome. Just use [markdown syntax](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/basics) instead of pure html ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at a CSS framework? They come with default classes you can use to set up something like that within a few short minutes. They also help producing cleaner html and interfaces that you can easily redesign at a later time.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are looking like this :- [**DEMO**](http://tinkerbin.com/it6pOZMa)

**CSS**

```
#container {
    height: 100%;
}

#rowOne {
    height: 50px;
    background: green;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
#rowTwo {
    background: limegreen;
    min-height:500px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:50px;
}
#rowThree {
    position: fixed;
    background: green;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    height:50px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id='rowOne'>row 1</div>
    <div id='rowTwo'>row 2</div>
    <div id='rowThree'>row 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be using Jquery to set the minimum height of the middle div to be the height of the screen, minus the height of the other two divs (100px)
something like this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var screenHeight = $(document).height() - 100px;

    $('#rowTwo').css('min-height' , screenHeight);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comment on jedrus07's answer:

> all this sollutions expand the center div behind the footer div. I want a solution with each div having only his own space.

The only way to do that is with CSS 3 calc(). If you don't need to support very many browsers, that's an option, and here's a demo of it in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/5QGgZ/3/

(Use Chrome or Safari.)

HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id='container'>
      <div id='rowOne'>row 1</div>
      <div id='rowTwo'>row 2</div>
      <div id='rowThree'>row 3</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, #container {
  height: 100%;
}
#rowOne {
  height: 50px;
  background: #f00;
}
#rowTwo {
  height: -webkit-calc(100% - 100px);
  background: #0f0;
}
#rowThree {
  height: 50px;
  background: #00f;
}
```

If you want wider browser support, you're going to have to go with a sticky footer solution like the ones jedrus07 mentioned, or Tom Sarduy's answer.